# Knitr + Latex can't write foreign characters (æ ø å) inside the R code boxes

Tags: pdftex, knitr

I cannot make Latex write æ ø and å when using Knitr, despite trying various solutions from other posts. I'm on a windows machine with windows 10 installed.
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
This will print out æ ø å 
<<>>=
# This will not print æ ø å 
@ 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code]

Things I tried from other suggestions that did not work:

- \usepackage{libertine}
- options(encoding = 'UTF-8')

Can anyone help me find a solution to this?

Comment: I don't have R to test but can't you use the classic tex commands `\ae`, `\o` and `\aa` ?

Comment: In RStudio, try `File>Reopen with encoding ...` and choose `UTF-8`. Save the file and recompile.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried, but this does now work in the knitr environment.
Ross I tried this now, but it doesn't change the output

Comment: I had a similar problem many years ago. Does this answer help? [Sweave doesn't seem to get .Rnw file encoding right](//stackoverflow.com/q/7509395)

Answer (score 3):

It's a good practice read the error messages in the console of RStudio if the compilation failed. In this case, the messages are very clear:

```
Line 1: LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.
Line 2: LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.
```

A more verbose message can be found in the .log file (clicking in "View Log"):

```
\usepackage may only appear in the document preamble, i.e.,
between \documentclass and \begin{document}.
```

So, move the 3th line to the top, *et voilá*:

**Edit**

The MWE has been changed in the question, so it produce now the correct output in a system using UFT-8 locale a .Rnw file saved with utf-8 encoding with TeX Live 2019 and  R 3.6.1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
This will print out æ ø å 
<<>>=
# This will not print æ ø å 
@ 
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Thus, this seems a problem not related with LaTeX, but the question is not providing enough information to reproduce the problem. Moreover, the MWE code is not still the code used to produce the image the question, since beside the problem to some characters in the R comment, there are not indentation in the LaTeX text (but there must be a 15pt indentation, as showed here).

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it the wrong way the first time, so this is not my problem. Please see the image for the actual problem. I have edited the question now.

Comment: was the output correct when you had the right order? that would indicate that the source of the problem is somewhere else than in the source code, since OP seems to have messed up the question the first time around.

Comment: @thymaro Yes. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! What OS did you compile this on? As I stated, I'm on a windows computer, which could likely be part of the problem. 

I did compile this and it's the same output as in the original post (I did leave out a \noindent but this doesn't change the problem). I'm not trying to hold back information here, I was just trying to keep the question as short as possible,

Comment: @MalteJensen I am on Linux, but this should not a problem if the file really have utf-8 encoding. Note that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is **not** the encoding of the file, is only what LaTeX must think about (BTW, today this is the default, so you can safely omit this line in a updated  distro). To be sure, in Rstudio, save it with menu  `File` >  `Save with Enconding ...` >   `UTF-8`.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the comment. I have just tried this, and the output is still the same. I think it might be a problem with my locale in R studio. I have tried setting it to "en_SE.utf8", but it won't let me do that. I don't know what to try from here, if that's the problem..